# TYPO3 form validation error

Tags: typo3, typoscript, typo3-6.2.x

I took over one site, which is based on TYPO3 CMS 6.2

I have a form, and I should improve validation, but I am not abble to find where are this error messages comming from.

here is (one label) template code:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="alternativeAbholungsadresseFirma" class="col-md-3 control-label"><f:translate key="LLL:EXT:speciality/Resources/Private/Language/locallang.xml:reclamation-new-form-company-label" /> 
    </label><!-- denis -->
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <f:form.textfield name="alternativeAbholungsadresseFirma" id="alternativeAbholungsadresseFirma" class="form-control" value="{args.alternativeAbholungsadresseFirma}" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance!
Denis

Comment: What is the error you are getting? A little more information would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the extension code, maybe there are some Domain Validations in the `Classes/Domain/Model/*.php` files. Also an Validation in the Controller Action is possible.

But without futher information nobody can help.

What error is display and what do you want do display?